# Organize columns on a webpage

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to make a square 2 x 2 grid with a rectangular column on the right-hand side.

I have tried using a grid system for the 2 x 2, but it messes with the rectangular column on the right.

Here is a reference:

[image]

Comment: Could you post your HTML and CSS rules as well?

Comment: That doesn't look like a 2x2 grid; that looks like a 3x2 grid with one cell spanning two rows.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2x3 grid you're trying to display. You need a container and 5 children in that container. Then you can apply CSS grid rules and particularly [`grid-template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) and [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area). Below is a demonstration of it looks like:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-areas: 
                  "one two five"
                  "three four five";
  grid-gap: 30px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 30px;
}

.item {
  background: #fff;
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
}
.two {
  grid-area: two;
}
.three {
  grid-area: three;
}
.four {
  grid-area: four;
}
.five {
  grid-area: five;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item one"></div>
  <div class="item two"></div>
  <div class="item three"></div>
  <div class="item four"></div>
  <div class="item five"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 4% 30% 1% 30% 1% 30% 4%;
    grid-template-rows: 2% auto 5px auto 2%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: grey;
}

#leftTop {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}

#leftBottom {
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-column-end: 5;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}

#centerTop {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 5;
}

#centerBottom {
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-column-end: 5;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 5;
}

#rightFull {
    grid-column-start: 6;
    grid-column-end: 7;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 5;
}

div {
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="leftTop">LT</div>
  <div id="leftBottom">LB</div>
  <div id="centerTop">CT</div>
  <div id="centerBottom">CB</div>
  <div id="rightFull">RF</div>
</body>
```

Easy to achieve with a grid-system. Its a grid with 3 columns and 2 rows. The right column just spans over 2 rows.